# Unable to create a CI pipeline using "only / except : changes"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following git repo structure:

```
.
├── docker
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements.txt
└── software
    ├── app
    │   └── app.py
    └── Dockerfile
```

The `docker` folder is responsible for create a docker image that will be used by my application.

Then if I change some file under the `docker` folder, I would like to recreate the `base image` and then create a new `app image` using the last `base image` created.

But if I only change my app, under the `software` folder, I would like to trigger only the stage for the app image.

Below my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - buildDockerImage
    - buildAppImage

build docker image:
    stage: buildDockerImage
    script:
        - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker build --target final --build-arg docker_image_version=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME docker
        - docker tag $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $CI_REGISTRY/xx/$APP_IMAGE_NAME:base
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/xx/$APP_IMAGE_NAME
    only:
        changes:
          - docker/**/*

build app image:
    stage: buildAppImage
    script:
        - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker build --build-arg app_image_version=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -t $APP_IMAGE_NAME software
        - docker tag $APP_IMAGE_NAME $CI_REGISTRY/xx/$APP_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/xx/$APP_IMAGE_NAME
    except:
        changes:
          - docker/**/*
```

The `only / except : changes` works fine to recognize the place of the change, but is not creating a pipeline with both stages if I change the `docker` folder. It creates only the `buildDockerImage`.

If I delete the `only / except : changes` configuration, the pipeline works as expected.

It it possible to achieve what I need ? I mean, I don't want to run the `buildDockerImage` if I only change my application, but if I do change the `base image` I need to run both `buildDockerImage` and `buildAppImage` in a pipeline.

Comment: Removing `except` and adding `only:changes: - docker -software` to `buildAppImage` should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to:

1. Build `buildDockerImage` only when `docker/**/*` location changes, so your current yaml for this stage is fine.
2. Build `buildAppImage`

   - always, just **remove** except clause from `buildAppImage` stage,
   - only for changes to docker locations, replace except with only and 2 locations:

```yaml
      only:
        changes:
          - docker/**/*
          - software/**/*
```

Comment: I removed the `except : changes`. Why was It avoiding the stage to be created ?

Comment: `only: changes: - <your pattern>` is the opposite of `except: changes: - <your pattern>`, so either first job was executed or the second.